# Repositories, UnitOfWork and Unity

Tags: c#-4.0, repository, unity-container, unit-of-work

Using Unity when I 'new up' an object that requires dependencies i.e. Repositories, UnitOfWork all is great, my new object gets the dependencies injected and the 'newed' up object has control over the UnitOfWork, the repositories as they also require a UnitOfWork dependency get injected too, with the same UnitOfWork (using PerResolve lifetime manager).

All's good, however where I have an issue is the scope of this UnitOfWork and Repositories are at the class level.

What if I would like the lifetime of the UnitOfWork to be controlled at the method level, how should I approach this ?? Should I be using method injection ? If so should my method be taking all the required dependencies i.e. Repositories and UnitOfWork again ??

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Unity does not offer HttpRequest Scoped Lifetime. So you can either manage your own life-time, or not use Unity (pretty much every other container, Autofac, Ninject, StructureMap, all support Http Request Scoped Lifetimes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Keep unit of work (wrap with DbContext) per request basis. If you use method wise it will be a costly solution. For example,

```
public void SaveAccount(Account account)
{
    using(var unitOfWork = unitOfFactory.CreateUnitofWork())
    {
       new Repository<Account>(unitOfWork).Attach(account);
       unitOfWork.Commit();           
    }       
}

public Account GetAccount(int id)
{
    using(var unitOfWork = unitOfFactory.CreateUnitofWork())
    {
      return new Repository<Account>(unitOfWork).Get(id);
    }
}

public void MakePayment(int fromAccount, int toAccount, decimal ammount)
{
   var from = Dao.GetAccount(fromAccount);
   var to = Dao.GetAccount(toAccount);
   from.Total -= amount;
   to.Total += amount;
   Dao.SaveAccount(from);
   Dao.SaveAccount(to);
}
```

We are using 4 different connections to the database in a single method also not safe use of transactions. User per request base unit of work can as a container you can use HttPContext.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using DI for method parameter, at least not directly.

The usual approach is to have an IUnitOfWorkFactory or some such. Get *that* out of the container. Then in your method call the factory to get your unit of work object. The factory may (or may not) go back to the container to do it's work.

Comment: Started down this route and stopped because I was then unsure how to then provide the repositories with the unit of work as I was not newing up the repositories (wanted to use DI) and was trying to avoid any reference to my unity container e.g container.resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Having a search on StackOverflow seems to suggest to pull the Http Request Lifetime Manager from the MVC project here:

http://mvcunity.codeplex.com/

Since Unity itself does not have it's own Http Request Lifetime Manager.

Other Questions:

[How to inject dependencies per http request (or per http context) with unity 2.0 and asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722433/how-to-inject-dependencies-per-http-request-or-per-http-context-with-unity-2-0)

[Using ASP.NET Session for Lifetime Management (Unity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707138/using-asp-net-session-for-lifetime-management-unity)